# cannot set bitmap from file URI

Tags: android

I have been trying to make a picture with the camera, and put this picture in my ImageView. First I found out that past version 24 you need to use the FileProvider, which seems to work now. However, whenever I try to create a BitMap from the URI, it remains `null`. I wonder what the path should be exactly, in order to create a bitmap from this?

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            "submit",
            ".jpg",
            storageDir
    );
    return image;
}

private void dispatchCameraIntent() throws Exception {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();

                Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), "com.example.daan.tvshowtracker.provider", photoFile);
                // Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path.toString());       <- also tried it this way
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), path);
                submitImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (photoFile != null) {
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }

            ......
        }
    }
```

The code above are the functions that I use to create the image and dispatch the camera. I do have provider settings in my Manifest, as well as a provider_paths.xml file in my res folder, as specified in different posts. The data I get back is:

`path: "content://com.example.daan.tvshowtracker.provider/external_files/submit111012311.jpg"`

`photofile: "/storage/emulated/0/submit111012311.jpg"`

Anyone knows why the bitmap still remains `null`? Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT: Updated with code**
I created the onActivityResult(), which returns the data from the intent. In the putExtra, I place my image file.

```
private void dispatchCameraIntent() throws Exception {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();

            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoFile);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
                Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), "com.example.daan.tvshowtracker.provider", photoFile);
                Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                submitImage.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
    }
```

However, when I get this data from the intent, it only shows a small black image? The data seems to be there though [image: Only displays this as image, instead of the image it took]

Comment: Use piccaso or glide library to easily handle bitmaps images from Uri

Comment: @AdityaSonel Is it the problem that the it cannot be easily loaded into a bitmap, or rather that it cannot even get loaded from external storage? I seem to think that it is the latter

Comment: `photoFile = createImageFile();`. Do not create the file already. A camera app may not like to overwrite an existing file. Moreover if the user does not take a picture you end up with an empty file. You only need a path to tell the camera app.

Comment: You are mixing up two methods of using the camera. And you are not using 'path' from `Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), "com.example.daan.tvshowtracker.provider", photoFile);`.
  `

Comment: @greenapps Indeed, whenever I put that instead of the actual file in the extra for the intent, the data in the onActivityResult seemed to be null.

Comment: Or you tell the camera app with EXTRA_OUTPUTin which file to store the image. And then you load a bitmap from the indicated file.

Comment: @greenapps There are two things i'd like to accomplish though: loading it into the imageview as preview, and sending it as file to my API, so I'd need the actual file there I assume (instead of just the path)

Comment: Or you omit EXTRA_OUTPUT and then you can get a bitmap (a thumbnail only) from Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data"); There is no file produced then by the camera app.

Comment: @greenapps That is what I tried, but it displays the bitmap in the imageview as a black block somehow then

Comment: Well adapt your code as now it indeed is a mess as you mixed it up. Read the two `Or`'s. Please remove the image. You let us scroll too much ;-).

Comment: `There are two things i'd like to accomplish`. Then go for EXTRA_OUTPUT. Well if you want to upload a full image and not only a thumbnail. If you want to upload a thumbnail then remove EXTRA_OUTPUT.

Comment: @greenapps Allright, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get a bitmap from the media store even before you took a picture.

You cannot do that before you called `startActivityForResult()`.

And also not after you called that.

You can only do that after the picture has been taken.

Do it `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: Ah, this seems very logical indeed. However, when I put the path in my intent (as a putExtra(..)) and try to capture it in the onActivityResult(), the `data` is `null` within this function?

Comment: You need to use putExtra() indeed for your uri. And Intent.EXTRA_OUTPUT. Just google for example. Please add it your post with the used intent and changed code.

Comment: I edited the post and added some code, wondering why it just displays a black image in my imageview when loading data from the intent

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code:
Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromView(idForSaveView);
            try {
                File file = new File(this.getExternalCacheDir(), "appdiam.png");
                FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
                fOut.flush();
                fOut.close();
                file.setReadable(true, false);
                final Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
                intent.setType("image/png");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share image via"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


      private Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
            Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
            Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
            if (bgDrawable != null) {
                //has background drawable, then draw it on the canvas
                bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
            } else {
                //does not have background drawable, then draw white background on the canvas
                canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
            view.draw(canvas);
            return returnedBitmap;
        }
```